# Scanning group of integers in the form of (x,y) in c

Tags: c

[image: Input from user]I am trying to take inputs from the standard input in the form (a,b) (c,d) (e, f) (g,h) and will stop taking input if an empty line is added. I need these inputs tuple by tuple like (a,b) first then I perform some computation with it like add in the binary tree and add (c,d) then (e, f) and so on in the following way:

```
insert_in_tree(&tree->root,&tree->root,a, b);
```

I know how to accept integers till empty line is added which i do in the following way:

```
AVLTree *CreateAVLTree(const char *filename)
{
    // put your code here
    AVLTree *tree = newAVLTree();
    int key, value;
    if(strcmp(filename, "stdin") == 0){
        char str[1024]={};
        printf("Enter your values");
        while( fgets(str, 1024, stdin) && strlen(str) && str[0] != '\n' ){
            printf("string %s", str);
            sscanf(str, "%d, %d", &key, &value);
            //int key = atoi(str);
            printf("This is key you entered %d\n", key);
            printf("This is value you entered %d\n", value);
        }
    }else{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r"); // open a file
    if(file == NULL) {
        return NULL;                                   // error checking
    }
    while (fscanf (file, " (%d,%d)", &key, &value) == 2)  // check for number of conversions
    //  space added  here ^
    {

        insert_in_tree_q5(&tree->root,&tree->root, key, value);
        //printf("%d,%d\n", key, value);
    }
    fclose(file);
    //node = tree->root;
}
    return tree;
}
```

but i am not sure how use this to solve my problem stated above.

Comment: look up `sscanf`.  i would read `str` via `fgets` as you are doing above and then call `sscanf` on `str`

Comment: @MFisherKDX  I tried this: sscanf(str, "(%d, %d)", &key, &value);
            printf("This is key you entered %d\n", key);
            printf("This is value you entered %d\n", value); 
but it returns me 0 and 0 everytime.

Comment: Check what [`sscanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). And use a debugger to see exactly what's read by `fgets`.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't you print the prompt (`printf("Enter your values");`) *before* you call `fgets`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, i edited that part and printed what is scanned by fgets. Now, the question is how to eliminate that and read only a and b.

Comment: That input you show, is it really copy-pasted correctly? It doesn't look correct (and definitely doesn't match the format you use for `sscanf`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude added a screenshot

Comment: Please paste the entire function, I think there is a mismatch between what you pasted and what you have.

Comment: @AhmedMasud done. Please check

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think what you are mentioning is the case when filename is provided in the else condition, which is working fine. The problem is in the if condition when the input has to be taken form the user.

Comment: You are typing garbage and not checking the return of sscanf.

Comment: @AkhilJain - yep, you are right. I'll put the pointy hat on and turn facing the corner `:)`

Comment: @Joshua I am not sure what you mean. I am printing the key and value that i scanned from sscanf.
any suggestions on what i should be doing ?

Comment: Those square boxes around question marks are stray characters.

Comment: Simple solution: Change the input format to not use parentheses or commas. I don't know what happens to your input, take look at it in a debugger to see the actual encoded values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using `scanf()` et.al. to parse data, as a simple `scanf("%d,%d")` tends to be error prone with differing user input.

My general approach when dealing with known formatting characters (like `(`, `,`, `)`), is to find them first with `strchr()`, validate they're somewhat sensible, and only then try to extract the value.

In the code below, I locate the parentheses and comma, then copy out the *possibly numeric* data in between, before handing it off to `strtol()` for converting the integer string to a numeric representation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER_LEN 32

/*
** Given a string which contains (somewhere) a pair
** of numbers in the form "... (x, y) ...", parse the pair
** into val1 and val2 respectively.
**
** Returns the point at which the input ended successfully
** or NULL on error
*/
const char *parseTuple(const char *input, int *val1, int *val2)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    char  val1_str[ MAX_NUMBER_LEN+1 ] = { '\0' }; 
    char  val2_str[ MAX_NUMBER_LEN+1 ] = { '\0' };

    // Find the first '('
    char *left_paren  = strchr( input, '(' );
    char *right_paren = strchr( input, ')' );
    char *comma       = strchr( input, ',' );

    // validate the things we found exist, and are in valid positions
    if ( left_paren != NULL && right_paren != NULL && comma != NULL &&   // needed parts exist
         left_paren < comma && comma < right_paren )                     // in the correct order

    {
        // val1 source string exists between left_paren+1 and comma-1
        int val1_len = comma-1 - left_paren+1 - 1;
        if ( val1_len > 0 && val1_len < MAX_NUMBER_LEN )
        { 
            strncpy( val1_str, left_paren+1, val1_len );
            val1_str[ val1_len ] = '\0';
        }

        // val2 source string exists between comma+1 and right_paren-1
        int val2_len = right_paren-1 - comma+1 - 1;
        if ( val2_len > 0 && val2_len < MAX_NUMBER_LEN )
        { 
            strncpy( val2_str, comma+1, val2_len );
            val2_str[ val2_len ] = '\0';
        }

        // If we extracted some reasonable numbers, try to parse them
        if ( val1_str[0] != '\0' && val2_str[0] != '\0' )
        {
            *val1 = strtol( val1_str, NULL, 10 );
            *val2 = strtol( val2_str, NULL, 10 );
            // TODO handle errno when string is not a number

            // if errono did not indicate a strol() failure
            result = right_paren+1;  // point to the next input location, so we can call again 
        }
    }

    return result;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *input;
    int val1;
    int val2;

    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        input = argv[i];

        do
        {
            printf( "From input of: [%s]\n" , input );
            input = parseTuple( input, &val1, &val2 );
            if ( input != NULL )
                printf( "    Parsed out: (%3d,%3d)\n", val1, val2 );

        } while ( input != NULL && strlen( input ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Giving the test-run:

```
$ ./parse_tuple '(-3, 2)' '(1,1)(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,0) () (,)' '(' '()' ')' '(,)' '(-12,)' '(123,456)'
From input of: [(-3, 2)]
    Parsed out: ( -3,  2)
From input of: [(1,1)(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,0) () (,)]
    Parsed out: (  1,  1)
From input of: [(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,0) () (,)]
From input of: [(]
From input of: [()]
From input of: [)]
From input of: [(,)]
From input of: [(-12,)]
From input of: [(123,456)]
    Parsed out: (123,456)
```

Comment: How do i call this parseTuple function inside my if(strcmp(filename, "stdin") == 0){...}.

Comment: After the `while( fgets( ... )` line is where it looks like it should go (replacing the sscanf).